# the application google chrome is not open anymore

Tags: google-chrome

on yosemite i now get chrome error when clicking link from skype or using alfred to open customized urls. the links and custom urls fail to open and instead I am presented with a dialog that says 'The application google chrome is not open anymore', even though the application is open.

[image: x]

any ideas what may be causing this issue?

Comment: FWIW this issue still exists in 2021 on Mojave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After restarting I can no longer reproduce the issue and chrome operates as normal.

Answer (score 5):

Killing Chrome using the terminal, and opening Chrome fixes the issue for me.

`ps -ef | grep '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`/