# TextEdit problem after inst. Catalina

Tags: macos, textedit

After installing Catalina, my in-built TextEdit doesn't work anymore, neither by clicking the icon nor from the application. It says
The application “TextEdit.app” is not open anymore.

Please advise me.
Thanks

Comment: Try opening TextEdit and when it doesn't succeed, press Command + Option + Esc to force quit the app. macOS might automatically prompt to send a report to Apple. What you need from here is the log. Please share this in your question. If the dialog doesn't appear, then launch TextEdit again to get it immediately after force quitting.

Answer (score 1):

The typical fix is to choose log out from the Apple menu when this happens.

This closes out your work more cleanly than trying to force quit apps. Also, it has the benefit of forcing the OS to name any apps that are not responding or have work to be saved.

Next, [restart the os](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175957/the-application-google-chrome-is-not-open-anymore) and possibly test making a new user account. Let us know how it goes...

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it helped to shut down and restart, and viola! back to normal. However the icon is gone from the dock, apparently the problem is with the icon.